# Fazer o update de um textview durante alguns segundos

Tags: java, android, thread

Queria implementar uma transição entre duas Activitys, onde o utilizador, via uma Progress Bar (já implementei) e uma textview onde a cada 2 segundos, aparece-me uma frase nova, por exemplo:

- A carregar informação...
- A implementar as duas definições...
- A concluir o registo...

Estiver a ver algumas soluções, só que não explicavam a maneira exata como devemos fazer o update da TextView, para já tenho o seguinte código:

```
updatingThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
//o meu problema em entender está a partir daqui, qual a forma mais correta de implementar o uptadate da textview?
                            textviewtoWait.setText(R.string.loadInfo);
                            textviewtoWait.setText(R.string.loadInfo2);
                            textviewtoWait.setText(R.string.loadInfo3);

                        }
                    });

                    updatingThread.start();
                }
```

Antes de usar a Thread, tinha uma transição com uma única TextView com uma única string e com uma Progress Bar com o seguinte código(**neste a TextView está no XML**)

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(actualContext, MainActivityProto.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("email", novoUtilizador.getEmail_utilizador());
                            myIntent.putExtra("nome", novoUtilizador.getNome());
                            startActivity(myIntent); // termina com a actividade anterior, o que impede o utilizador de voltar atras.
                            finish();
                        }

                    }, 5000);
```

**EDIT**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button txttoRegister, txttoLogin;
    private EditText editTextUser, editTextPassword, addUser, addEmail, addLocal, addPassword, addTelm;
    private TextView textviewtoTitle, txtviewtoMainPage, txtviewtoSecondMain, textviewtoWait;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private Toolbar toolmenubar;
   // private Thread updatingThread;




    final Thread updatingThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Array com os valores que serão exibidos no textviewtoWait
                final int[] txts = {R.string.loadInfo, R.string.loadInfo2, R.string.loadInfo3 };

                while (!isInterrupted()) {

                    // Vamos iterar a lista para atualizar o textviewtoWait
                    for(final int  txt : txts){
                        // aguarda 2 segundo...
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        // Runnable responsavel por atualizar a tela...
                        final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                   textviewtoWait.setText(txt);
                            }
                        };

                        runOnUiThread(updateUI);
                    }

                    // este irá sair do while, pois já realizamos as ações!
                    break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        txttoRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontoRegister);
        txttoLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontoLogin);
        textviewtoWait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewtoWait);


        changeTextFontFamily();

        txttoRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        txttoLogin.setOnClickListener(this);




        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Carnevalee Freakshow.ttf");
        sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);
        String login = sharedpreferences.getString("LOGIN", null);


        if (login != null) {

            MyDBHelper dbHelper = new MyDBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Utilizador WHERE email_utilizador = '" + login + "'", null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivityProto.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("nome", cursor.getString(1));
                myIntent.putExtra("email", cursor.getString(0));
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }


        }
    }

    /**
     * Algoritmo e metodo para fazer ligação aos cliques dos botões eixstentes na aplicação.
     *
     * @param v
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttontoRegister) {
            alertDialogtoRegist();
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttontoLogin) {
            final Context actualContext = this;

            String userName = editTextUser.getText().toString();
            String passWord = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

            MyDBHelper dbHelper = new MyDBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            if (!userName.matches("") && !passWord.matches("")) {

                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Utilizador WHERE email_utilizador = '" + userName + "'", null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String pass_utilizador = cursor.getString(2);

                    /*Verifica a igualdade das passwords*/
                    if (pass_utilizador.equals(passWord)) {
                        final Utilizador novoUtilizador = criarUtilizador(cursor);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("LOGIN", novoUtilizador.getEmail_utilizador());
                        editor.commit();

                        setContentView(R.layout.transition_to_mainpage);

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(actualContext, MainActivityProto.class);
                                myIntent.putExtra("email", novoUtilizador.getEmail_utilizador());
                                myIntent.putExtra("nome", novoUtilizador.getNome());
                                startActivity(myIntent); // termina com a actividade anterior, o que impede o utilizador de voltar atras.
                                finish();


                    } else {
                        apresenta_toast("A password que introduziu está errada!");
                    }

                } else {
                    apresenta_toast("Utilizador inexistente na plataforma!");
                }
            } else {
                apresenta_toast("Não é possível fazer login, senão introduzir nenhum dado!");
            }
        }

    }





    /**
     * Método para colocar todos os botões e edittexts com o mesmo tipo de letra
     */
    private void changeTextFontFamily() {


        txttoRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontoRegister);
        editTextUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_username);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_password);

        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Carnevalee Freakshow.ttf");

        txttoLogin.setTypeface(face);
        txttoRegister.setTypeface(face);
        editTextUser.setTypeface(face);
        editTextPassword.setTypeface(face);

    }

    /**
     * Algoritmo para a criação de uma AlertDialog para permitir o registo de novo utilizador
     * na plataforma.
     */
    private void alertDialogtoRegist() {

        final Context actualContext = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogtoRegist = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registerdialog, null);

        textviewtoTitle = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txttoTitleRegisto);

        addUser = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.edittoAddUser);
        addEmail = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.edittoAddEmail);
        addLocal = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.edittoAddLocal);
        addPassword = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.edittoAddPass);
        addTelm = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.edittoTelm);
        txtviewtoMainPage = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txttoTitleRegisto);


        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Carnevalee Freakshow.ttf");
        textviewtoTitle.setTypeface(face);

        addUser.setTypeface(face);
        addEmail.setTypeface(face);
        addLocal.setTypeface(face);
        addPassword.setTypeface(face);
        addTelm.setTypeface(face);


        dialogtoRegist.setView(myView);
        dialogtoRegist.setPositiveButton(R.string.registobutton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                MyDBHelper dbHelper = new MyDBHelper(actualContext);
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                try {
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Utilizador(email_utilizador, nome, password, localizacao) VALUES ('" + addEmail.getText().toString() + "', '" + addUser.getText().toString() + "', '" + addPassword.getText().toString() + "', '" + addLocal.getText() + "')");
                    apresenta_toast("Utilizador criado com sucesso!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    apresenta_toast("O utilizador que pretende criar já existe! Tente Novamente!");
                }

            }

        });

        dialogtoRegist.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogtoRegist.create();
        alertDialog.show();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updatingThread.start();
    }


    /**
     * Algoritmo para a criação de um novo utilizador na plataforma.
     *
     * @param cursor_utilizadores
     * @return
     */
    private Utilizador criarUtilizador(Cursor cursor_utilizadores) {

        Utilizador newUtilizador = new Utilizador();
        newUtilizador.setEmail_utilizador(cursor_utilizadores.getString(0));
        newUtilizador.setNome(cursor_utilizadores.getString(1));
        newUtilizador.setPassword(cursor_utilizadores.getString(2));
        newUtilizador.setLocalizacao(cursor_utilizadores.getString(3));

        return newUtilizador;
    }

    /**
     * Algoritmo de impressão de toasts basicamente de impressão
     *
     * @param mensagem
     */
    private void apresenta_toast(String mensagem) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }


}
```

Erro quando o código `setText()` não está comentado:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference

Quando está comentado, mostra o layout da transição por nem 1 segundo:

```
setContentView(R.layout.transition_to_mainpage);
```

E depois entra logo no Intent, que vai reedireccioná-lo para a Activity seguinte.

Eu queria que ele mostra-se o R.layout.transition... com essa actualização da TextView.

**SOLUÇÃO**

```
private void mainThread() {


        final Thread updatingThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Array com os valores que serão exibidos no textviewtoWait
                    final int[] txts = {R.string.loadInfo, R.string.loadInfo2, R.string.loadInfo3};

                    while (!isInterrupted()) {

                        // Vamos iterar a lista para atualizar o textviewtoWait
                        for (final int txt : txts) {
                            // aguarda 2 segundo...
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            // Runnable responsavel por atualizar a tela...
                            final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {


                                    textviewtoWait.setText(txt);


                                    // TextView.class.cast(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transition_to_mainpage, null).findViewById(R.id.txtviewtoWait)).setText(txt);
                                }

                            };

                            runOnUiThread(updateUI);
                        }

                        // este irá sair do while, pois já realizamos as ações!


                        break;

                    }
                    irParaProximaActivity();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        updatingThread.start();


    }

    private void irParaProximaActivity() {
        actualContext = getApplicationContext();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(actualContext, MainActivityProto.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("email", novoUtilizador.getEmail_utilizador());
        myIntent.putExtra("nome", novoUtilizador.getNome());
        startActivity(myIntent); // termina com a actividade anterior, o que impede o utilizador de voltar atras.
        finish();
    }






 LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transition_to_mainpage, null);

                textviewtoWait = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtviewtoWait);
                setContentView(myView);

                mainThread();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja isto que queria fazer:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textviewtoWait;

    final Thread updatingThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Array com os valores que serão exibidos no textviewtoWait
                final int[] txts = {R.string.loadInfo, R.string.loadInfo2, R.string.loadInfo3 };

                while (!isInterrupted()) {

                    // Vamos iterar a lista para atualizar o textviewtoWait
                    for(final int  txt : txts){
                        // aguarda 2 segundo...
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        // Runnable responsavel por atualizar a tela...
                        final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                textviewtoWait.setText(txt);
                            }
                        };

                        runOnUiThread(updateUI);
                    }

                    // este irá sair do while, pois já realizamos as ações!
                    break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textviewtoWait = TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.textviewtoWait));


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updatingThread.start();
    }



}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Só uma questão deixo o esse código no método onCreate()? ou coloco-o dentro do Handler com 5 segundos?

Comment: Você pode colocar dentro do **onStart()**

Comment: Quando corro o programa tanto no método onStart(), como no onCreate(), bem como dentro do Handler, não actualiza a TextView pois dá uma "nullpointerexeption" quando faz o setText()...

Comment: Coloquei o código inteiro, fica mais fácil pra você entender!

Comment: vou testar, mas só uma anotação, eu quero que esta actualização da TextView e como disse na pergunta, seja uma transição entre dois Fragments. Para conseguir, invoco o método onStart() no método onClick()?

Comment: Então, no **Onclik** você chama o novo Fragment, e este no **onStart**, ou seja ao ser carregado, vai carregar o Loading  atualizar o **TextView**

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, com base nas suas indicações, verifique por favor o código que coloquei na edição para verificar senão estou a cometer algum erro. A TextView está em comentário, mas mesmo assim não funciona, o NullPointerException.

Comment: Mesmo comentado dá o **NullPointer**?? Pode acidionar o log com o erro? Fica mais fácil!

Comment: já pode ver a edição, adicionei também alguma informação sobre o que aconteco e o que pretendo que aconteça.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54595/discussion-between-thiago-luiz-domacoski-and-bullprog).

Comment: Obrigado Thiago! Depois de muita conversa no chat, conseguimos resolver o problema. Vou colocar a solução na minha pergunta como Edit!